# Angular2 http.get results in a Mixed Content error or No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: angular, browser-sync, mixed-content, angular2-http, lite-server

I am trying but unable to do a http.get request.

Below is the relevant parts of the `Service` I am using.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class StockService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getStocks() {
        var url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=np";
        this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(function(info){
            console.log(info);
        });
    }
}
```

I know that the url *http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=np* is valid because I am able to run a get request with it in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

I am using [npm-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) to run my app and it gets loaded at *http://localhost:3000*

Running at *http://localhost:3000* results in the error : **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=np. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

I thought that the problem could be that my app is running on http and needed to be on a https to properly do the get request, so I created a *bs.config.json* file. npm-lite allows us to use options from [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options) to run. I set the https to be true to allow my app to run on https.

*bs-config.json*

```
{
    "https" : true
}
```

Now when I run my app it will run on 'https://localhost:3000' and I get the error: 
**zone.js:101Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:3000/portfolio' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=np'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

I am unsure of how to proceed from here. Please let me know if I am properly setting up a http get request or if I am misunderstanding something. Thanks!

============================================

EDIT 1: in response to @AngJobs recommendation of : *just add a special header in your request for cross browser request*

I added a header in the request :

```
getStocks() {
    var url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=np";
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.get(url, options).toPromise().then(function(info){
        console.log(info);
    });
}
```

I am back to running on http://localhost:3000  but now get the error: **XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=np. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)**

Comment: Put back "https" : false

Comment: And resolve the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  error, just add a special header in your request  for cross browser request

Comment: hi @AngJobs Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out, but I get another error. Please check my latest edit to see the implementation

Comment: It all has to do with CORS policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the ultimate problem was that the yahoo servers were not authenticating `CORs`. 
A simple solution to solve this is to use a `proxy`. The one I am using for now is : https://crossorigin.me/. In order to use this proxy, I just need to append the request url with **https://crossorigin.me/**.

There is no need to mess with request headers and I can continue to run the app on http:localhost

```
getStocks() {
    var url = "https://crossorigin.me/https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=np";
    this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(function(response){
        console.log(response._body);
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set http content type in header and also make sure the server is authenticating CORS

```
 //NOT A TESTED CODE
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
```